# ServiceStack Parse Xml Request to Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, servicestack

One of our requirements is to have a decoupled architecture where we need to map data from one system to another, and the intermediate mapping is handled by a ServiceStack service request.  Our issue is that a vendor can only provide data via Xml that does not conform to the standard dictionary request that ServiceStack offers like below:

```
  <Lead xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>String</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>String</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
  </Lead>
```

Instead they need a mechanism like:

```
<Lead>
  <LeadId>Value</LeadId>
  <FirstName>First Name</FirstName>
  <LastName>Last Name</LastName>
  ...
</Lead>
```

Since the nodes in their xml request may change over time, and we're simply acting as a middle-man, is there a native way to accept a dynamic request or handle this as Dictionary with data similar to what's below?

```
Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "LeadId", "Value" },
    { "FirstName", "First Name" },
    { "LastName", "Last Name" }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Yes.  Can you provide an xml file with a few entries.  I'm not 100% sure how an input with more than one entry would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default XML Serialization doesn't provide any way that you could transparently infer an XML fragment into a string dictionary so you're going to need to manually parse the XML which you can do in ServieStack by telling [ServiceStack to skip built-in Serialization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) by implementing `IRequiresRequestStream` which ServiceStack will inject with the Request Stream so you can deserialize it yourself, e.g:

```
public class Lead : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

In your Service you'd then manually parse the raw XML and convert it to the data collections you want, e.g:

```
public class RawServices : Service
{
    public object Any(Lead request)
    {
         var xml = request.RequestStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes();

         var map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         var rootEl = (XElement)XDocument.Parse(xml).FirstNode;

         foreach (var node in rootEl.Nodes())
         {
             var el = node as XElement;
             if (el == null) continue;
             map[el.Name.LocalName] = el.Value;
         }

         return new LeadResponse {
             Results = map
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a very similar method yesterday, evening using the RequestStream.  Glad to know I was using a good method.  Thank you very much!